# What is happening when calling wait() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I read in a Java textbook the following pertaining to multi-threading.

> For a thread to call wait() or notify(), the thread has to be the owner of the lock for that object. When
>   the thread waits, it temporarily releases the lock for other threads to use, but it will need
>   it again to continue execution.

I'm confused about what is meant by the clause

> When the thread waits, it temporarily releases the lock for other
>   threads to use

I don't get what that clause is talking about. Is it saying that when the `wait()` method is called it is actually releasing the lock before the `wait()` returns (i.e. this happens without caller knowing)? Or is it just alluding to `wait(timeout)` releasing the lock when the timeout elapses? If it is the former why would it release the lock before `notify()`? This seems like a vague and poorly explained statement.

Comment: Before calling `wait()`, the thread owns the lock, after calling `wait()`, the thread give up the lock, and wait for notify, on returning from `wait()`, it owns the lock again. Always call `wait()` with in a `while()` loop, it helps to check condition both before & after get the lock. JUST write a demo using `wait()` and `notify()` / `notifyAll()` to see how it works, you can't understand it without impl it by yourself.

Comment: Calling `wait()` (or its timeout overloads) _must_ release the lock otherwise how could another `Thread` obtain the lock in order call `notify()`/`notifyAll()`? Also, note that a `Thread` obtains a lock of an `Object` by using `synchronized (someObj) {...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For a thread to call wait() or notify(), the thread has to be the owner of the lock for that object.*

Otherwise, a runtime error occur and the rest of code is not executed.

*When the thread waits, it temporarily releases the lock for other threads to use*

In more details, call to *wait()* does the following:

- the lock is released
- current thread is registered as waiting in the monitor
- processor switches to some other thread ready for execution

Then, some thread calls *notify()* or *notifyAll()*, which causes one or all threads which are registered as waiting at this monitor to be moved from the wait set to the ready set, waiting for a free processor to execute.

*but it will need it again to continue execution.*

This means the execution of the thread is continued with executing *synchronized* statement to regain the lock. After the lock is aquired, then the *wait()* method returns. *wait(timeout)* differs in that except for *notify()* or *notifyAll()*, it also can return upon the timeout.

In sum, you need to understand how a thread switches between following 4 states:

- running on a processor
- blocked on *synchronized* statement
- waiting for notification
- ready to execute and waiting for a free processor

Answer (score 1):

When a thread calls wait, the thread releases the lock right away and then goes dormant until either the timeout expires, if any, or until it receives a notification, which occurs when another thread acquires the same lock that the waiting thread gave up and calls notify on it (also the scheduler has to pick the waiting thread from among any other waiting threads; calling notify doesn’t notify a given thread, it tells the scheduler to pick a thread from a given lock’s wait set to notify).

Once the thread is woken up by a notify, it has to reacquire the lock in order to leave the wait method, because the thread is still inside of a synchronized method or block. That is what the quote means when it says the thread will need the lock to resume execution.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread calls `wait()`, it's temporarily releasing the monitor (lock) of the object until it receives a notification from another thread. This way, a thread can willingly give control (that it has, in the first place) of the object's monitor to another thread. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html):

> The invocation of `wait()` does not return until another thread has
>   issued a notification that some special event may have occurred —
>   though not necessarily the event this thread is waiting for (so always
>   invoke `wait()` inside a loop that tests for the condition being
>   waited for).
>
> ...
>
> When `wait()` is invoked, the thread releases the lock and suspends
>   execution. At some future time, another thread will acquire the same
>   lock and invoke Object.notifyAll, informing all threads waiting on
>   that lock that something important has happened.